# How to determine whether a month corresponds between to dates

Tags: excel-formula

I need to extract the month of column "E" and place it on column "B" = Month.

The table on column A is located on a separate worksheet than the table between column E and G.

Structure of both tables:

[image: table structure]

Comment: Why is november 3 times at the top of the list, december at the bottom and so on ... ? Basically you can use `MONTH`.

Comment: or may be you can try in cell B2 =TEXT(A2,"MMMM"), can you clarify more of your question and expected result, like July?

Comment: It looks like you want the month to start on the 21st. Modify @12Rev79's suggestion to read `=TEXT(A2-21,"MMMM")`